# Drupal - Custom page with arguments

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7, arguments

I am looking to hook every URL that starts with /questions to one template file.

So for example:

1. /questions
2. /questions/question1
3. /questions/question1/respond
4. /questions/question1/somethingelse

all of the above should go to my template questions.tpl.php
Then within my questions.tpl.php I want to do stuff with the arguments.

Is there a way to do this? I have been searching for a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in your custom module by using

> preprocess_page hook

.
For more information refer link
[Template Based on URL Alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39908/change-templates-based-on-path-alias)

Comment: This helps, but my title is still page not found.